# Mongoose Checking/Handling authorisation on save

Tags: node.js, mongoose, everyauth

In a mongoose schema I'd like to check if a user my save a file.
Using everyauth I've got it to work, but it throws an error with the full stacktrace into the console.

```
SpotSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
   if(!everyauth.user){
        // throws the errror
        next(new Error('Not Logged in'));
        return;
    }
   next();
}
```

Is there a way to handle this more gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

dont throw
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

check error handling part and handle the error in your save function